# Stirling like approximation for lower-incomplete gamma function?

Tags: approximation, gamma-function

May we have a similar approximation for [lower incomplete gamma function $\gamma(s,x)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Lower_incomplete_Gamma_function), as we have a [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) for [Gamma function $\Gamma(s)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: Did you try Laplace's method?

Comment: I did try a Laplace method, and I came up with the same Stirling aprrox. as we have for $\Gamma(x)$, because Laplace method don't care about the limits of integral. And lower gamma incomplete function is only different from gamma function in limits.
By the way, your advice of using Laplace method was useful !